# Using a property of a subclass of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, nsmutablearray

My code functions properly, but I am getting warnings, so I think I can do this better.  I have a subclass of NSObject (Objects) and I have a subclass of Objects (subObject).  I have a property declared in subObjects.  I store many objects that are all different subclasses of Objects in a single NSMutableArray.  Sometimes, I go through the array and do certain things to certain objects.  I read from my array like this:

```
//I have declared an Objects "myObject" earlier in my code.
//c is an int used to select an object from the array
myObject = [arrayObjects objectAtIndex:c];
```

In this case, I am accessing my property declared in subObject as

```
[myObject property]
```

The code works because I have it set up so it should not be able to get to this piece of code without being a subObject.  However, I am getting a warning because the computer does not know this.  It only knows that myObject is an Objects, not a subObject.  How do I fix this and get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is sure that all objects in the NSMutableArray are of type SubObject (type names should start with an upper case character), then you have these possibilities:

- you can declare the item you extract as SubObject directly:

  ```
  SubObject *myObject = [arrayObjects objectAtIndex: c];
  [myObject setProperty: 17];
  ```
- or you cast:

  ```
  Object *myObject = [arrayObjects objectAtIndex: c];
  [(SubObject*)myObject setProperty: 17];
  ```
- or you simply use *id*. If you use *id*, the compiler assumes nothing and will not issue a warning:

  ```
  id myObject = [arrayObjects objectAtIndex: c];
  [myObject setProperty: 17];
  ```

Comment: Thank you!  I am sure it is much more efficient not to have to make another object.

Comment: yes, but you said that the property was defined for the SubObject Class - so if the array contains several object types (Object, SubObj1, SubObj2,..) as I understood (or missunderstood?) then the first suggestion will not work correctly. Also, you only need to introduce another variable (which is a pointer anyway!) if you might do something else with that object if it's not of type SubObj. Which again (I might have misunderstood) - only as a remark, I tend to force as much (type)checking as possibly before runtime - using id certainly works - but might give you ugly errors later...

Comment: If he didn't extract anything yet, and it is sure that all are of type SubObject, then it should work. Otherwise he can cast, or use ids.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the object you get from the array is declared of the subObject type BEFORE your "making sure" that all is correct. Then the compiler will not give the warning anymore...

eg. something like:

```
Object objO;

objO = [myarray objectAtIndex: n];

if (myMakingSure) {
    SubObject objS;
    objS = (SubObject) objO;
    x= [objS getProperty];
}
```

ps also make sure, that you accept answers if they are correct - otherwise one may be hesitant to answer your questions... (I didn't know at the very beginning and also got a nice note about that)

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this and the error is gone and it seems to be working.  The only problem with the code you posted is that I needed to get objS from the array again.  BTW: This is the first question I have gotten a legitimate answer to.

Comment: It is a bit overdone, though: there is no need to introduce an extra variable and assign to it. Just cast the original variable to the type you want. Or use one of the alternatives, see my answer.

Comment: what do you mean with "having to get again" - why can't you just get it at the very beginning and do it like I suggested. Could you please explain Thanks